# Apply function by grouping two columns and saving it into a new column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Having the following df `data.frame` in R:

call of df:

```
Id1 Id2   var1    var2
A  CODE_1 9625    0.110 
A  CODE_1 10625   0.210
A  CODE_2 3441    0.0604
A  CODE_2 22372   0.237
A  CODE_3 4611    0.0792
A  CODE_3 2859    0.0530
B  CODE_1 2295    0.0308
B  CODE_1 4398    0.0474
B  CODE_2 2464    0.0353
B  CODE_2 342     0.0596
B  CODE_3 2600    0.229
B  CODE_3 429     0.0762
```

How Could I apply the next function:

```
myfun<- function(x,y,z,w){
  output <- list()
  output$den <- (x-z)/sqrt(((x*(1-x))/y)+((z*(1-z))/w))
  return(output)
}
```

and get finally:

```
Id1 Id2    var1    var2   Val
A   CODE_1 9625    0.27   -16.1
A   CODE_1 8625    0.19   -16.1
A   CODE_2 3441    0.0604 -35.6
A   CODE_2 22372   0.237  -35.6
A   CODE_3 4611    0.0792  4.5
A   CODE_3 2859    0.0530  4.5
B   CODE_1 2295    0.0308  -3.440912
B   CODE_1 4398    0.0474  -3.440912
B   CODE_2 2464    0.0353  -1.82
B   CODE_2 342     0.0596  -1.82
B   CODE_3 2600    0.229   10.3
B   CODE_3 429     0.0762  10.3
```

The code essentially takes Id2 and Id2 like the following manual process:

```
A  CODE_1 9625    0.27   
A  CODE_1 8625    0.19
```

and apply the function, saving the result in a column in the corresponding order, as shown in the example.

```
myfun(0.110,9625,0.19,8625)$den

A  CODE_1 9625    0.27   -16.1
A  CODE_1 8625    0.19   -16.1
```

At the momento Im trying some methods like:

```
df %>% group_by(Id1, Id2)%>%select(var1, Var2)%>% xxxxxxx
```

Im feeling like the `xxxxxxx` is mostly one simple line but Im lost..

Comment: Check the input and output dataset values for 'var1' and 'var2'.  There seems to be some difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can modify the function

```
uni_prop.test <- function(x,y,z,w){  
    (x-z)/sqrt(((x*(1-x))/y)+((z*(1-z))/w))

  }
```

and then after grouping by 'Ti','Exp', create the 'var3' by taking arguments as the `first` and `last` value of 'var1' and 'var2'.  Here, we assume that there will be only two observations per each group (based on the example)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(Ti, Exp) %>% 
   mutate(var3 = uni_prop.test(first(var2), first(var1), last(var2), last(var1)))
```